# RabbitMQ crash rabbit_disk_monitor

Tags: rabbitmq, jackrabbit, rabbitmq-exchange, rabbitmqctl

crash exception log as below:

2022-12-06 03:40:44 =ERROR REPORT====
** Generic server rabbit_disk_monitor terminating
** Last message in was update
** When Server state == {state,"c:/Users/appadmin/AppData/Roaming/RabbitMQ/db/rabbit@FR-PPA004-mnesia",50000000,79131406336,100,10000,#Ref<0.526994179.3769630732.93858>,false,true,10,120000}
** Reason for termination ==
** {eacces,[{erlang,open_port,[{spawn,[67,58,92,87,105,110,100,111,119,115,92,115,121,115,116,101,109,51,50,92,99,109,100,46,101,120,101,32,47,99,32,100,105,114,32,47,45,67,32,47,87,32,34,92,92,63,92,"c:","\","Users","\","appadmin","\","AppData","\","Roaming","\","RabbitMQ","\","db","\","rabbit@FR-PPA004-mnesia",34]},[binary,stderr_to_stdout,stream,in,hide]],[{file,"erlang.erl"},{line,2272}]},{os,cmd,2,[{file,"os.erl"},{line,275}]},{rabbit_disk_monitor,get_disk_free,2,[{file,"src/rabbit_disk_monitor.erl"},{line,255}]},{rabbit_disk_monitor,internal_update,1,[{file,"src/rabbit_disk_monitor.erl"},{line,209}]},{rabbit_disk_monitor,handle_info,2,[{file,"src/rabbit_disk_monitor.erl"},{line,181}]},{gen_server,try_dispatch,4,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,689}]},{gen_server,handle_msg,6,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,765}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,226}]}]}
2022-12-06 03:40:44 =CRASH REPORT====
crasher:
initial call: rabbit_disk_monitor:init/1
pid: <0.436.0>
registered_name: rabbit_disk_monitor
exception error: {eacces,[{erlang,open_port,[{spawn,[67,58,92,87,105,110,100,111,119,115,92,115,121,115,116,101,109,51,50,92,99,109,100,46,101,120,101,32,47,99,32,100,105,114,32,47,45,67,32,47,87,32,34,92,92,63,92,"c:","\","Users","\","appadmin","\","AppData","\","Roaming","\","RabbitMQ","\","db","\","rabbit@FR-PPA004-mnesia",34]},[binary,stderr_to_stdout,stream,in,hide]],[{file,"erlang.erl"},{line,2272}]},{os,cmd,2,[{file,"os.erl"},{line,275}]},{rabbit_disk_monitor,get_disk_free,2,[{file,"src/rabbit_disk_monitor.erl"},{line,255}]},{rabbit_disk_monitor,internal_update,1,[{file,"src/rabbit_disk_monitor.erl"},{line,209}]},{rabbit_disk_monitor,handle_info,2,[{file,"src/rabbit_disk_monitor.erl"},{line,181}]},{gen_server,try_dispatch,4,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,689}]},{gen_server,handle_msg,6,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,765}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,226}]}]}
ancestors: [rabbit_disk_monitor_sup,rabbit_sup,<0.281.0>]
message_queue_len: 0
messages: []
links: [<0.435.0>]
dictionary: []
trap_exit: false
status: running
heap_size: 6772
stack_size: 28
reductions: 35778
neighbours:

Anyone have idea on what is the error?
Appreciate with your help. Thanks.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Spring, so I removed that tag. It is better to ask questions about RabbitMQ itself on the rabbitmq-users Google group - the RabbitMQ engineers don't monitor Stack Overflow closely.

Answer (score 0):

You **must** provide the RabbitMQ and Erlang version any time you ask a question or report an issue with RabbitMQ. In fact, **any** time you are talking about software, providing versions is necessary!

This is the important part of the error text:

```
{eacces,[{erlang,open_port,[{spawn,[67,58,92,87,105,110,100,111,119,115,92,115,121,115,116,101,109,51,50,92,99,109,100,46,101,120,101,32,47,99,32,100,105,114,32,47,45,67,32,47,87,32,34,92,92,63,92,"c:","\","Users","\","appadmin","\","AppData","\","Roaming","\","RabbitMQ","\","db","\","rabbit@FR-PPA004-mnesia",34]},
```

`eacces` means that there is a permission issue. Since I don't know what version of RabbitMQ you are using, my *guess* is that the free disk space check errors because RabbitMQ/Erlang can't start up Powershell or `cmd.exe`.

I have fixed issues around free disk space monitoring as well as to make RabbitMQ more UTF-8 friendly (in case you are using a non-English) language.

My suggestion is to upgrade to the latest RabbitMQ (3.11.4) and Erlang (25.1.2). If that does not resolve your issue, you should start a new discussion [here](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/discussions).